# java swing timer works fine in debug but not in runtime

Tags: java, swing, timer, frame-rate

I've been trying to work this one for hours now and i am at a lost.I want to run my game at 30 fps. the swing timer delay is set to 1000/30. Even if i slow it down to 1000 or 2000 it doesnt change anything. In step by step debug everything works as intended. The "updateALL()" method is called the next time the timer refresh. But in runtime updateAll is never called, not even once (the sysout never prints). Ive trimmed down the code below just to show the essential parts. It should compile.

This is my listener class:

```
public class Observer implements ActionListener {

    private int timerFrame;
    private int fps;
    private boolean frameComplete;

    public Observer() {
        this.frameComplete = true;
        this.timerFrame = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aEvent) {
            nextTimerFrame();
    }

    public void frameCompleted() {
        frameComplete = true;
        System.out.println("Fcompleted");
    }

    public int getTimerFrame() {
        return timerFrame;
    }

    public void setFps(int fps) {
        this.fps = fps;
    }

    private void nextTimerFrame() {
        System.out.println(timerFrame);
        if(frameComplete) {
            if(timerFrame == fps) {
                timerFrame = 1;
            } else {
                ++timerFrame;
            }
            frameComplete = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is the code in my GameClock Class:

```
public class GameClock {
    private Timer timer;
    private Observer observer;
    private GameEngine gameEngine;
    private View view;
    private boolean paused;
    private boolean quit;
    private int clockFrame;

    public GameClock() {}
    public GameClock(GameEngine gameEngine) {
        this.gameEngine = gameEngine;
        this.paused = false;
        this.quit = false;
        setupTimer();
        this.clockFrame = 0;
        run();
    }

    public void updateAll() {
            readInputs();
            updateGameEngine();
            updateCanvas2D();
            updateCanvas3D();
            clockFrame = clockFrame == 30? 1:clockFrame+1;  
            observer.frameCompleted(); // puts frameComplete at "true" in Observer
            System.out.println("update" + clockFrame);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(!quit) {
            int timerFrame = observer.getRefreshFrame();
            if(!paused && (clockFrame < timerFrame || (clockFrame == 30 && timerFrame == 1))) {
                updateAll();
                //System.out.println("update");
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupTimer() {
        int fps = Config.getFps();
        int delay = Math.round(1000/fps); 
        observer.setFps(fps);
        this.timer = new Timer(delay, observer);
        timer.start();
    }   
    private void readInputs() {

    }

    private void updateGameEngine() {
    }

    private void updateCanvas2D() {
    }

    private void updateCanvas3D() {
    }
}
```

Update:

some weird observation:

if i put 2 sysout inside the "if" statement of my while loop they never print. This gives no printout:

```
public void run() {
    while(!quit) {
        int clockFrame = observer.getRefreshFrame();
        //System.out.println("clock" + clockFrame);
        //System.out.println("frame" + refreshFrame);
        if(!paused && (refreshFrame < clockFrame || (refreshFrame == 30 && clockFrame == 1))) {
            System.out.println("clock" + clockFrame);
            System.out.println("frame" + refreshFrame);
            updateAll();
            //System.out.println("update");
        }
    }
}
```

If i put the previous sysout in comments and remove the // from the 2 outside the "if" statement like this:

```
public void run() {
    while(!quit) {
        int clockFrame = observer.getRefreshFrame();
        System.out.println("clock" + clockFrame);
        System.out.println("frame" + refreshFrame);
        if(!paused && (refreshFrame < clockFrame || (refreshFrame == 30 && clockFrame == 1))) {
            //System.out.println("clock" + clockFrame);
            //System.out.println("frame" + refreshFrame);
            updateAll();
            //System.out.println("update");
        }
    }
}
```

i see that refreshFrame is always incremented with clockFrame. This makes no sense. If updateAll is never called refreshFrame shout not be incremented.

UPDATE 2 - some explanations:

- A swing timer needs a listener and generates an actionPerformed() event when it ticks. Thats why i need an observer.
- I cant make the timer call "updateAll()" directly because the timer is on its own thread. If i do that the timer might call an "updateAll()" while the previous update has not completely finished.
- The way it "should" work: the while keeps looping doing nothing until it sees the timer has ticked (the clockFrame is lower than the timerFrame). It then updateAll(). The timerFrame cant be incremented unless the last updateAll() has completely been finished (frameComplete set to true at the end of updateAll). Once the update is finished the next timer tick will increment the timerFrame thus generating a new update.
- In theory and in step by step debug it works but not at runtime.

Comment: It's hard to be sure, but I'm guessing you're `while-loop` is blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing, amongst other things, the `Timer` from ben triggered.  I'm kind of wondering while you need the `while-loop` and the `Timer`, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Consider providing a [mcve] which demonstrates "how" you're using your classes

Comment: i've updated my post with more observations.  The timer is incremented, the sysout inside nextRefreshFrame() is printed periodically. If i understand correctly the timer has its own thread.

Comment: I find the code confusing. You have a "refreshFrame" variable in both classes, but in one class you also call it a clockFrame. You have a loop and a Timer. Generally you just have a Timer, which replaces the logic of a loop. In the Timer you then change the state of the variables in your class. Not sure why you even have the Observer class.

Comment: tks, i have updated my post to give more explanations and i changed the variable names to make then less confusing.

Comment: 1. Please post mre as advised. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem. 2. I do not see `observer` initialized in `GameClock` 3. _timer might call an "updateAll()" while the previous update has not completely finished_  swing `Timer` can safely do all gui updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a one-file [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (copy-paste the entire code into `GameClock.java`) demonstrating use of a swing `Timer` to update a swing `View` at 30fps:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GameClock {

    private final Observer observer;
    private final View view;

    public GameClock() {
        view = new View();
        observer = new Observer(view);
        setupTimer();
    }

    private void setupTimer() {
        int fps = 30;
        int delay = Math.round(1000/fps);
        observer.setFps(fps);
        Timer timer = new Timer(delay, observer);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameClock();
    }
}

class View {

    private JLabel counter;

    View(){
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    void createAndShowGui(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        counter = new JLabel("0", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        f.add(counter);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    void setCounter(int i){
        counter.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}

class Observer implements ActionListener {

    private int timerFrame;
    private int fps;
    private final boolean paused;
    private final View view;

    public Observer(View view) {
        this.view = view;
        paused = false;
        timerFrame = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aEvent) {
        if (! paused) {
            updateAll();
        }
    }

    public int getTimerFrame() {
        return timerFrame;
    }

    public void setFps(int fps) {
        this.fps = fps;
    }

    private void nextTimerFrame() {
        timerFrame = timerFrame >= fps ?    0 : timerFrame + 1;
    }

    public void updateAll() {
        nextTimerFrame();
        view.setCounter(timerFrame);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks, im short on time because of the coro virus but i will try that soon. If the problem is solved ill come back to select your post as the answer. I think i did not understand what a mre is. If im not mistaken now it means to put all your code in one file that can be executed easily?

Comment: I wasnt fast enought to edit my previous comment... Tks, but there is a small problem with the solution. I need my observer to be 100% independent, it is a requirement for the project. The class Observer wont have access to GameEngine. Otherwise i would just call gameEngine.updateAll() directly from the Observer with a condition to check if the last update has ended.  I think i did not understand what a mre is. If im not mistaken now it means to put all your code in one file that can be executed easily? Im short on time because of the coro virus, ill try to update my post asap. tks again

Comment: If the timer runs on `GameClock` and you want it to directly update  `GameEngine` you can do so without an observer. What is the responsibility of the observer though ?

Comment: There are a few things I can point out about MRE: 1. It does not represent your specific application but a focused specific problem you are trying to solve. 2. It should be M: remove all what is not essential. Bare minimum. 2. It should be R: . it should reproduce the problem. 3. It should be complete. Avoid dependency on data-base, files or other unavailable resources. 4. It should be easy to use (copy-past).  You're asking people here to volunteer to solve your problem, 
 and you should make it as easy as possible for them to do so.

Comment: c0der tks for your help, it was much appreciated. I followed your advice and implemented the ActionListener inside my GameClock class. It now calls updateAll() directly and it works. I kept the independant observer for my inputs. Hopefully this will satisfy my teacher. The observer is supposed to handle all game events (ie all listeners) and the swing timer works on an ActionListener by design.